# Counting special zero elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A = [0 3 4; 5 0 6; 0 6 0]`;

I know that to compute the total number of zero elements, I can simply use the function `find`. That is, `Total_number_of_zero_elements = length(find(A==0));`
and this will give me 4.

**PROBLEM:**

Take for example now the matrix B generated as follows:

```
B = toeplitz(0.1.^(0:30-1));
Total_number_of_zero_elements = length(find(B==0));
```

The code above will give: Total_number_of_zero_elements = 0.
The matrix B contains a lot of 0 values but are written as 0.0000.

So matlab can't discriminate between 0 and 0.0000 using the function find?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: `sum(abs(B)<=eps)` or replace that `eps` with a custom tolerance value?

Comment: Also, if you have an element `B(i,j)` which is 0.0000, then check `format long e; B(i,j)` to see that it's not actually 0 but around `1e-15` .

Comment: Ok! I understand now; Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floating-point numbers have the property that they are not represented exactly. If you numerically multiply a matrix with its inverse, the off-diagonal elements won't be 0, but around `eps(1)`.

In order to check the zero-ness of floats, use a threshold: `find(abs(B)<1e-10)`. (Note the `abs`: without that `-10` would also qualify as 0.)

Obviously the threshold should be chosen carefully: large enough that numerical zeros are caught, but small enough to let actual nonzeros stay nonzero.

In your example

```
B = toeplitz(0.1.^(0:30-1));
```

the smallest number is `1e-29`, which is easily representable as a double-precision number, and it's obviously not equal to 0. If you do this further, you'll bump into problems starting around `eps(0)`, which is roughly `5e-324`. Any number larger than that will not be exactly zero. (But if you perform computations and *expect* the result to be 0, then it will likely be on the order of `eps(1)` as I wrote above.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!